# Generating SQL query that will ignore where clause if no condition is given in it using sequelize & node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using node.js as backend language & Microsoft SQL as database. And I am using sequelize (http://docs.sequelizejs.com) to query with SQL. Below is my Web API route handler code :

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = {
getinfo(req, res) {
  let {search, id, fromDate, toDate, firstName, lastName} = req.body;
  const condition = "";

  if(search != null && search != '')
  {
      condition += "id LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
      condition += "fromDate LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
      condition += "toDate LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
      condition += "firstName LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
      condition += "lastName LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
  }

  if(fromDate != null && toDate != null && fromDate != '' && toDate != '')
  {
      condition += "date BETWEEN" + fromDate + "AND" + toDate;
  }

  const query = "";
  query = " SELECT * from TABLE where" + condition;
  sequelize.query(query, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT)
  .then( ...)

 }
}
```

I wanted to make a scenario where even if condition is empty, the query should return the database. Initially I thought of using `if` in condition variable to check if condition variable has anything there or not.

```
if(condition != '' && condition != null) {
    query = " SELECT * from TABLE where" + condition;
} else {
    query = " SELECT * from TABLE " ;
}
```

But it wasn't working as expected (due to asynchronous nature of JavaScript). I want to make an SQL query itself that will check if there is any condition present in `where` clause or not, if not then it should return the whole table. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The standard trick is to prepend `1=1` to the list of conditions.  And (maybe) later append the extra conditions using `AND condition`:

---

```
const condition = " 1=1";

  if(search != null && search != '')
  {
      condition += " AND id LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
      condition += " AND fromDate LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
      condition += " AND toDate LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
      condition += " AND firstName LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
      condition += " AND lastName LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
  }

  if(fromDate != null && toDate != null && fromDate != '' && toDate != '')
  {
      condition += " AND date BETWEEN " + fromDate + " AND " + toDate;
  }

  const query = "";
  query = " SELECT * from TABLE where" + condition;
  sequelize.query(query, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT) ...
```